# Comparing two variables containing an instance of a Singleton

Tags: java

Say I have two variables abc and xyz as follow:

```
Untitled abc = Untitled.getInstance();
Untitled xyz = Untitled.getInstance();
```

How do I compare these two to check if both contains the same instance ? I mean I want to verify if Untitled is a Singleton class or not.

Comment: `abc == xyz`, but why do you need that? Unless this code is a unit-test of `Untitled`, this smells of bad design.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I asked a question in  #java on IRC,if a class with a non-final class variable is singleton? As I just learned about singleton pattern. And was curious to know if this class  http://pastebin.com/2NXDPv1i is singleton or not. So some guy assured me that it's a singleton,which it is not. That's all this experiment was about.

Comment: As has been said, just because a factory method returns the same object twice doesn't mean it's a singleton. For every test you create (that finishes in a finite time), I can create a non-singleton that convinces your tests nevertheless.

Comment: In fact, creating a singleton tester is impossible. The best you can do is (provably singleton / not provably singleton / provably not singleton), and even that requires bytecode inspection.(assuming you want option #1 to ever fire)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking two questions here if I'm not mistaken.

To check if abc and xyz are same instances, just use the '==' operator. It checks for reference equality.

```
if (abc == xyz)
{
  //true
}
```

To check if an object is an instance of a particular class,

```
if(obj instanceof ClassName)
{

}
```

Comment: My comment to the question still applies: This smells of a design flaw.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Very much agreed.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare both variables `a == b` to see if they reference the same object, but it would'nt necessary mean they are a singleton, two variables pointing to the same object would return the same value if compared like this too.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reference of both abc and xyz. You will see the same result.
`if(abc==xyz)` it will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

For JUnit Test, You can use something like this.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertSame;

assertSame("Objects are not same ",expected, actual);
```

It verifies if (expected == actual) and doesn't invoke call on equals() method.